# A question about a gtk's function —gtk_vbox_new()

Tags: c, gtk

I am a beginner in gtk, there are some codes to constuct a simple Simple menu:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *vbox;

GtkWidget *menubar;
GtkWidget *fileMenu;
GtkWidget *fileMi;
GtkWidget *quitMi;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Simple menu");

vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
fileMenu = gtk_menu_new();

fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");

quitMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");

gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileMi), fileMenu);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), quitMi);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), fileMi);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quitMi), "activate",
G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
return 0;
}
```

What does the "vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);" mean? I look gtk_vbox_new() function in gtk Devhelp", it tells me that this function returns a GtkVBox — A vertical container box, who can tell me what this is? I have no idea about "vertical container box".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the "vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);" mean?

---

> Packing boxes are invisible widget containers that we can pack our widgets
>   into and come in two forms, a horizontal box, and a vertical box. When
>   packing widgets into a horizontal box, the objects are inserted
>   horizontally from left to right or right to left depending on the call
>   used. In a vertical box, widgets are packed from top to bottom or vice
>   versa. You may use any combination of boxes inside or beside other
>   boxes to create the desired effect.

hbox:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

vbox:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
| 4 |
+---+
| 5 |
+---+
```

`gtk_vbox_new` is deprecated in the current version (GTK3), now we should use:

```
gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10); /* where 10 is an arbitrary padding */
```

or

```
gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);
```